# I'm a bit stuck with array/object manipulation

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting, d3.js

I have a raw JSON file, which looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXhvN.jpg). In it, it contains 18 objects, each of which contains information about a particular Premier League football week. In each of these 18 match week information objects, it contains 20 objects about the teams, including their position, goals etc. This is how it looks:[nested structure of my JSON.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx4Dp.jpg)

The relevant information I want out of it is the team and its relevant position for that week. So effectively, I want 18 snapshots of the league table each week. However, the format I need the information it has to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOlun.jpg). That is, it needs to be an array of arrays, wherein each array, it contains the team's name, and then a week by week league position separated by commas. In the picture, there is only the first week's league position, but I need each week's position in there, so each array object in the array should be 17 items long.

I've tried for ages to get the information from the first form into the second (that is, from the nested JSON into the array of arrays), but I just can't seem to manipulate the data in the right way. I've tried sort functions and nested loops, but I just can't seem to do it.

This is how my code currently looks (using the d3.js library to do a load of getting requests).

```
  <script>

var count = 21
var requests = new Array()

//This generates an array of get requests
for (i=1; i<count; i++) {
  requests[i] = d3.request("http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/445/leagueTable/?matchday=" + i)
  .header("X-Auth-Token", "")
}

var q = d3.queue();
//This uses the d3 queue function to make 16 get requests for the data, and
//then once all the data is retrieved (awaitAll), it excutes the callback function
  for (i=1; i<count; i++) {
  q.defer(requests[i].get);
}
  q.awaitAll(function(error, files) {
  if (error) throw error;
  //This converts the retrieved files to a JSON
  var Matchdays = new Array()
  for(i=0; i<count-1; i++) {
    Matchdays[i] = files[i].response
    Matchdays[i] = JSON.parse(Matchdays[i])
  }
  console.log(Matchdays)

//This makes a table in the required format for Week 1. I need all the other Weeks
// to follow the numbers that are already there, however.
var Week1Table = new Array()
  for(i=0; i<count-1; i++) {
Week1Table[i]= [Matchdays[0].standing[i].teamName, Matchdays[0].standing[i].position]
}

console.log(Week1Table)

})



  </script>
```

Comment: So this 'Week1Table[i]= [Matchdays[0].standing[i].teamName, Matchdays[0].standing[i].position]' what you want in the end, but for every MatchDay?

Comment: Well, sort of. I actually want it to look like, for example, Week1Table[0] = ["Manchester United FC", 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5...], where the numbers are that relevant team's league position for each consecutive week. Trouble is, in the original JSON, each matchday object has the teams all move around position from week to week, if you see what I mean.

Comment: I'm a little curious as to why you need to transform the data.  The way it's being delivered seems like it would be easier to work with, especially if you are building something with d3...

Comment: I'm actually using c3.js, which requires the data in quite a specific form. I haven't fully learnt how to use d3 yet. But thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Get your list of teams from the first element’s standings array.   Build an array for each team out of the team name and its position from each match day located in the set.  If a team is not found in a following match day its position for that day will be -1.

Assuming your initial array is called `arr`

```
var out = arr[0].standing.map(function (s) {
  return [s.teamName].concat(arr.map(function (el) {
    var team = el.standing.find(function (s1) {
      return s1.teamName == s.teamName;
    });
    if (!team) return -1;
    return team.position;
  }));
});
```